# Is it possible to use pexpect to run another python script on switch?

Tags: python-3.x, spawn, pexpect

Connecting to switch using expect spawn

```
child = pexpect.spawn('telnet ' + self.device_ip, timeout = 30)
```

When trying to run the below line, Im getting nothing as output

```
child.sendline('python script.py')
```

Can someone help me to run the python file over here?

I used

```
print("%s"%(child.before))
```

to print the output but it prints nothing

Comment: When I try to spawn `python -m module`, `pexpect.before` gets value `pydev debugger: process 15208 is connecting`, then EOF exception.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you are using `child.before` that you have a `child.expect` statement beforehand.  To put simply expect defines the text buffer that before references. Ex.

> child = pexpect.spawn('telnet ' + self.device_ip, timeout = 30)
>
> child.sendline('python script.py')
>
> child.expect('user@abcd1234>')
>
> remotehostoutput = (child.before)

Comment: Also, don't forget to set terminal length :).